# React, Typescript, custom renderer and JSX.IntrinsicElements

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am attempting to achieve the following structure in JSX:

```
<ComponentWithCustomRender>
  <section someattribute=""/>
</ComponentWithCustomRender>
```

I'm not able to rename the nested `section` element (long story). Currently this JSX will conflict with `JSX.IntrinsicElements` defined in the React typings.

Somehow we need to tell Typescript that the lowercase elements within `ComponentWithCustomRenderer` are not using `JSX.IntrinsicElements` but instead use some other set of definitions.

Note that augmenting/overriding `JSX.IntrinsicElements` is not a good option, because in our case `section` element has different semantics depending on whether it is used inside or outside `ComponentWithCustomRenderer`.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly is the error you are getting? The only problem that you have in the sample above is that "section" element does not have "someattribute" defined - but that I assume is not the real code you have.

Comment: @Amid, our `section` element will have custom attributes, and the Typescript compiler complains about these because it treats `section` as an HTML element and not _our_ intrinsic element. The `section` element is defined in `JSX.IntrinsicElements` in the React typings and Typescript uses this for all JSX elements with initial lowercase letter (see Intrinsic elements section of this page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)

Comment: I do not think this is typescript restriction. The react itself clearly stipulate how it treats elements starting with lowercase letters: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Comment: In this case there is a custom renderer, so the normal React rules don't apply. Also, this scenario could apply to something entirely unrelated to React (might not even be a browser app) where JSX is nevertheless used.

Comment: For people stumbling across this thread, I also raised this suggestion on the Typescript issues board: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15266